# Simple Bridge with netplan doesn't work (19.10)

Tags: networking, network-manager, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, netplan

I hope you can help me. I'm pretty sure the solution is quite simple, but so far I'm unable to put the finger on the problem....

I'm trying to setup a network bridge adapter with Netplan to use it with my KVM guest machine. I followed a couple of tutorial, including [the one on Netplan.io](https://netplan.io/examples) and so far none of these worked.

As of right now, my configure looks like this (01-netcfg.yaml) :

```
network:
  version: 2
#  renderer: networkd
  renderer: NetworkManager

  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: yes

  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
```

which is "almost" a copy-paste from the Netplan website tutorial. But when I check with networkctl, i got this :

```
● 1: lo
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: loopback
           State: n/a (unmanaged)
         Address: 127.0.0.1
                  ::1

● 2: enp3s0
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: n/a (unmanaged)
            Path: pci-0000:03:00.0
          Driver: r8169
          Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           Model: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Onboard Ethernet)
      HW Address: 1c:1b:0d:ef:08:d6 (GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.)
         Address: 10.0.0.50
                  fe80::d47d:fce7:1e9c:54f4
         Gateway: 10.0.0.1 (TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.)

● 3: virbr0
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: bridge
           State: n/a (unmanaged)
          Driver: bridge
      HW Address: 52:54:00:b9:f4:aa

● 4: virbr0-nic
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: ether
           State: n/a (unmanaged)
          Driver: tun
      HW Address: 52:54:00:b9:f4:aa

● 23: br0
       Link File: /usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: bridge
           State: n/a (unmanaged)
          Driver: bridge
      HW Address: c6:d9:4f:71:c2:62
```

The *br0* bridge I've just created is always with the State unmanaged, and when I check my KVM host to which the card is connected, the network is not detected.

As i said at the beginning, I'm pretty sure the error is obvious but I can't find it. So any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have a problem with who is trying to get an address through DHCP (it should be the bridge, NOT the physical device).

Both your OS and the KVM guests will get their DHCP config from the bridge.

This is my working configuration:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces:
        - enp5s0
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
```

Make sure there is NO DHCP in the interface and only on the bridge.

Also, after `sudo netplan apply`, make sure to reboot, it is more reliable than restarting the network.

Any particular reason you're getting NetworkManager to be the renderer? (makes sense if this is a laptop or desktop, but it's unnecessary in a server).

Comment: Well, it seemed that switching from NetworkManager to networkd was the trick! I now need to learn to use openVPN with networkd....how hard can it be ;)

Comment: I would think that `NetworkManager` should still be able to manage a VPN connection through a device managed by `networkd`, but it's just a feeling, I have nothing solid to base it on.